# Excel VBA Columns B and C OR Column D required

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a spreadsheet which is used enterprise-wide. I am trying to put in checks such that certain fields are required. Specifically, columns B (last name) AND C (first name) are required, OR Column D (Organization) is required. However, B, C, and D cannot all three be filled in. If the row has any data at all in it, B and C or D are required.

My idea is to put in a button to run this macro. That I can do.

I've tried many things at this point. I can include the spreadsheet in case anyone can offer any insight. I had a macro that worked on a test sheet, but does not work on this sheet, if that will help at all.
Here is the macro

```
Sub CheckVal2()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsCurr As Worksheet
Dim cel As Range
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim lngRow As Long

For Each ws In Worksheets
    If Left$(ws.Name, 7) = "Current" Then
        Set wsCurr = ws
        Exit For
    End If
Next

With wsCurr
    lngLastRow = .Range("B5000").End(xlUp).Row
    For lngRow = 2 To lngLastRow
        For Each cel In .Range("B" & lngRow & ":E" & lngRow)
        If cel = "" Then
        MsgBox "First and Last Name or HCO must be populated."
        Cancel = True
        Exit Sub
        End If

            If cel <> "" Then
               If .Cells(lngRow, "D") = "" Then
                    If .Cells(lngRow, "B") = "" Or _
                    .Cells(lngRow, "C") = "" Then
                    MsgBox "First and Last Name or HCO must be populated."
                    Cancel = True
                    Exit Sub
                        End If
                    End If
                End If


        Next
    Next
End With
'
End Sub
```

Comment: Here is the macro

Comment: When you say "does not work", what do you mean exactly? Is an error returned, or is the MsgBox not being displayed when it should be, or being displayed when it shouldn't be, or is something else happening? Also, how does the "test sheet" differ from "this sheet"?

Comment: Thanks for your questions. The test sheet starts at row 2. The error I receive is, "Run Time Error 91 Object variable or with block variable not set"

And when I hit Debug, the following line is highlighted 
    lngLastRow = .Range("B5000").End(xlUp).Row

Comment: So when the error occurs, what is `wsCurr` referencing at that point? Perhaps it was not set in the preceding `For` loop, e.g. because no "Current" sheet exists.

Comment: It sounds like you don't have a worksheet that contains "Current" as the first 7 characters of the worksheet name.  Check whether one does exist, that there are no typos in the name (e.g. "Curent") and no case differences (e.g. "current").  It may be an idea to include (for testing purposes) a `MsgBox ws.Name & " found"` just before `Set wsCurr = ws`.

Comment: Consider using Excel [Data Validation](http://superuser.com/questions/536862/data-validation-require-nearby-cell-not-be-blank) with formulas so that it will work even if macros are disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you get past whatever is causing the error trying to access wsCurr (which I suspect is just a case of the worksheet not existing), you should modify your code as follows:

```
With wsCurr
    lngLastRow = .Range("E5000").End(xlUp).Row
    For lngRow = 2 To lngLastRow
        'First check whether first/last name has been consistently advised
        If (.Cells(lngRow, 2) = "") <> _
           (.Cells(lngRow, 3) = "") Then
            MsgBox "Row " & lngRow & " - First Name and Last Name must both be advised or both be blank"
            Cancel = True  ' I assume this is a global variable?
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'Now check that last name has not been advised if HCO has been, and vice-versa
        If (.Cells(lngRow, 2) = "") = _
           (.Cells(lngRow, 4) = "") Then
            MsgBox "Row " & lngRow & " - First and Last Name, or HCO, must be populated but not both."
            Cancel = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
End With
```

This will get around the existing problem with your tests, which (as far as I can tell) aren't allowing for the case where all three columns have been advised.

I also changed the column on which lngLastRow was being set because, if it is set based on column B and the last row(s) of your data only contained values in column C and/or D, those final row(s) would not be being tested.

Comment: Thank you so much. The end of a long day and I did not remember I still had the worksheet title there. Thank you, this solution works great.

Comment: A few things. First of all, thank you. This does mostly work. However, it always generates the message. "First and Last Name, or HCO, must be populated but not both." If there is data in column E, this message is generated regardless of contents of B, C, or D. Also, I would prefer this check to start at row 19. Do you have any suggestions? I hate to take up so much of your time.

Comment: Firstly, if you want to start your checks at row 19, change `For lngRow = 2 To lngLastRow` to `For lngRow = 19 To lngLastRow`.  Secondly, the `"First and Last Name, or HCO, must be populated but not both."` message should only be displayed if column B and D both contain something, or if column B and D are both empty.  But if B is empty and D is populated, or D is populated and B is empty, then it shouldn't be appearing.  Place a breakpoint on the `MsgBox` line which is generating that message and then have a look at the value of `.Cells(lngRow, 2)` and `.Cells(lngRow, 4)`.

Comment: @MatthewIngle - I have updated the answer to include the row number causing the error in the error message (i.e. started the messages in the MsgBox statements with `"Row " & lngRow & " - `).  Modify your code the same way so that you can tell easily which row is generating the error.  It may be generating the error because your data has a space in a cell (test will fail because " " <> "") or something equally non-obvious.  (If it is a space, we can easily amend the code to `Trim` the values before using them in the test.)

Comment: Again, thank you. This worked very well. You must be right and I had an errant value in the row.